# VB.NET Rotating button in a circular Motion

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a Spin the Wheel and i want to use a button for a componets. Is it possible to rotate a button into a circular motion? I already use to rotate it using this one

```
button1.left = button1.left+10
```

but it only move on a straight line. Can anyone give me some tips on how to create a spinning wheel better?

Comment: You can't rotate a control. You should look into drawing an `Image` on a `PictureBox` in its `Paint` event handler and rotating that `Image`. Specifically, you will need to use the `RotateTransform` method of the `Graphics` object provided. Do some appropriate research first and make your best attempt, then ask a new question if you encounter an issue.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming that this is a Windows Forms application, so you should have tagged the question as such. If it's not WinForms then the answer would be different.